# Why does TypeScript allow a different subclass to fit into a different slot?

Tags: typescript

Given:

```
class Base {}
class D1 extends Base{}
class D2 extends Base{}

const d1: D1 = new D1();

function printD2(d2: D2) {
    console.log(d2)
}
printD2(d1);
```

I would have expected an error passing `d1` into `printD2`. They are structurally the same, yet they are derived types. Why is this? How to prevent this? At runtime this `d1 instanceof D2` would return `false`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8C+AoUkYBECM0CAHgC4IB2AJjPBAmpuFNDgEyGkXVyIOYD25CCWiU8ALhYEAvNHIIA7lIAUASgDc6dADMAruWAkAloOgAHAE5HyJNssqtJbVSnTR30YIIj8QCAHQg-ADm9qyq6BiW1ras9ngaQA

Comment: That is the correct expected behavior: Typescript is structurally typed not nominally typed. You can get around this by giving the derived classes some unique property to make them structurally different.

Comment: TypeScript uses structural typing. Whenever two types are structurally the name, they are considered “compatible”.